# How can I move the top panel to the bottom in Gnome 3?

Tags: panel, gnome-shell, top-bar

Is there a way to move the top panel to the bottom in Gnome 3? It is very annoying to have this panel at the top, because then I have to aim for the close button when I want to close a window. When the panel is at the bottom, I can simply throw the mouse pointer to the corner. Big usability issue.

Comment: are you referring to gnome-shell or gnome-classic?

Comment: looks like the same or similar question here:  Chris - if you can confirm this then I'll merge both questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/632090/how-to-move-top-panel-to-bottom-in-ubuntu-15-04-with-gnome-3-16-2

Comment: https://tipsonubuntu.com/2020/04/17/enable-single-bottom-panel-ubuntu-20-04-lts/ GNOME Tweaks gives you a single bottom panel that combines both Dock and the top panel (i.e. not what the OP asks, but related). You can install GNOME Tweaks from Ubuntu Software (the shopping bag with "A" icon), but still have to run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` for the single bottom panel.

Comment: @Catomic That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

An easy way to move the panel to the bottom of the screen is [MMOD Panel by rik](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/).

Open the [link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/) in Firefox and activate the extension with the switch in the left area.

The extension also works in GNOME 3.18 (tested on my system).

[image]
<sup>Screenshot taken from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/)</sup>

Comment: possible to get this panel look on mate of xfce?

Comment: If you're running in a virtual machine, this extensions doesn't cope with resizing the screen - the bar jumps back to the top as soon as the screen is resized.

Comment: Looks like there is some error when installing on `GNOME Shell 3.36.9`

Answer (score 9):

Install this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/208/panel-settings/
Than just change to `Bottom`
[image: menu that has been added by extension]

Note: As of Y13M09D16, this extension is not compatible with Ubuntu 13.04 using the Gnome3 desktop. In order to use this extension you will need to revert back to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. (Please update this note if the extension is updated for 13.04)

The last update of this extension was in 2012, which means the extension might be in the process of being abandoned as a project. To help contribute towards developing the extension please contact the developers at the projects development home page:
https://github.com/eddiefullmetal/gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: Not maintained any more.

Answer (score 6):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [**BottomPanel**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/949/bottompanel/) by abstract (not to be confused with the one from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/484424/)).

This extension moves the GNOME top bar to the bottom of the screen:
[image]
(screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

It may not *officially* support the recent GNOME shell versions, but in practice it works well with even version 3.36.x (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

You may visit its [GitHub page](https://github.com/Thoma5/gnome-shell-extension-bottompanel) for more info.

Comment: All I had to do in Ubuntu 18.04 was:  Show Application (nine dots at the bottom of Dock) > Ubuntu Software (the shopping bag with "A" on it) > search "Bottompanel" > install.  Works immediately. No funny business about a browser extension.

Answer (score 3):

### In Gnome Classic:

Hold down the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key (the key in between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> at the bottom left, usually, the key has the Windows logo on it) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Then, take your mouse and hold down the LEFT click on the top panel then you should see a hand gesture as if it grabbed something. Drag this hand to the bottom and it should make the panel be at the bottom.

### In Gnome3:

For Ubuntu 13.04, there is currently no way to move the top panel. The extension below is not compatible with Ubuntu 13.04 and it is not clear if it will ever be updated for compatibility.

In Ubuntu 12.04 you can try going to the previously mentioned website:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/208/panel-settings/

...then click the on/off switch which will ask you to install the extension. After this simply click on the user icon (top panel, farthest right hand icon by default) and select "Panel Settings" --> "Edge" --> "Bottom".

Answer (score 1):

With pressing <kbd>SuperKey</kbd>+<kbd>LeftAlt</kbd>+<kbd>RightMouse</kbd> you will get options so you can customize your panel as you wish. Hope you can fix it how you want.

Comment: That short-cut only works in GNOME classic session.

Comment: Great! This works like a charm! You have to press `Windows key` + `Left Alt` + `Right mouse` on panel you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released an extension that does exactly this. Only supported on v3.10 though.

Get it at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/828/bottom-panel/