# Gnome3 - Can't change top panel black color

Tags: gnome

No matter the shell theme I select in tweak-tool, the top panel is always black. Only with certain themes the font changes.

I have installed themes that are supposed to have a transparent panel (like Zukitwo and Nord), but nothing changes the black panel.

Comment: You might have an answer here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/132786/how-can-i-move-the-top-panel-to-the-bottom-in-gnome-3

Comment: Have you logged out or rebooted? Sometimes you need to do that to make the theme fully work.

Comment: Yes, is something that has been going on for ages on my system.