# How to move top panel to bottom in Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome 3.16.2?

Tags: 15.04, gnome-tweak-tool, gnome-shell-extension

I have recently upgraded to Gnome 3.16.2 (not sure what version I hade before) and then my MMOD Panel extension was no longer compatible. I only get the message "Does not support shell version".
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/

The same goes for the Panel Settings extension. This didn't work on my previous version either. 
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/208/panel-settings/

I absolutely loved having the top panel at the bottom and was wondering if there was a setting or extension that would fix this in my version. I have tried searching google with no luck.

The Taskbar extension embedded in Tweak Tool has only the option "add bottom panel", which does not move the top, but simply adds one on the bottom.

Comment: If what you want is a "classic desktop" maybe you should check fallback mode or the gnome shell fork: cinnamon.

Comment: I actually just wanted to move the top panel. because I like everything else, but cinnamon looks like it might be up my alley.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension [BottomPanel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/949/bottompanel/) works with GNOME Shell 3.16.2

```
% gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.16.2
```

[image]