# Top Bar to the bottom

Tags: gnome, unity-dash, panel, dock

Title says everything.

I am used to throwing my mouse to the top right corner and then closing stuff. In Ubuntu, I always have to aim. I see no benefit in having the bar at the top, the bottom is just much better.

Apparently, this could be done by [MMOD Panel by rik](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/) but installation always leads to an Error in Ubuntu 21.
I know of Dash to panel, but I like to have them separately. The clock and date in Dash to panel with everything on the site is not good.

Is there really no way to get this bar from the top to the bottom? Seems like such an easy and helpful thing to do.

Comment: The design language in GNOME is "worse is better".  You might find it better to use a different [flavour](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).  You can "Try Ubuntu" booting from installation media without affecting your installed system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move the top panel to the bottom in Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132786/how-can-i-move-the-top-panel-to-the-bottom-in-gnome-3)

Comment: [How can I move the top panel to the bottom in Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132786/how-can-i-move-the-top-panel-to-the-bottom-in-gnome-3)

Does not work. 
BottomPanel Is Incompatible
Panel Settings Is Incompatible
MMOD Panel delivers ERROR upon Installing

Answer (score 3):

**"Outdated" BottomPanel extension**

The Gnome Shell extension [BottomPanel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/949/bottompanel/) by abstract was a very simple extension that did just that, move the panel to the bottom. It is, unfortunately, not anymore updated, but it is so simple that you can make it work on Gnome 40.

- Download the code and copy it to the appropriate location as explained under "To use" on the extension's [github](https://github.com/Thoma5/gnome-shell-extension-bottompanel) page.
- Change the single line in the extension's `json` file (`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/bottompanel@tmoer93/metadata.json`) and change the Shell version to your current version as in

  {"shell-version": ["40.4"], "name": "BottomPanel", "uuid": "bottompanel@tmoer93", "description": "Moves the GNOME panel to the bottom of the screen"}

Log out then back in, and then enable the extension from the "Extensions" tool (not installed by default - if needed, install `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`).

**Supported extensions that do more than moving the panel**

The panel can be moved to the bottom with some supported extensions, but unfortunately, they are "heavier", i.e., do multiple things. There is the  [MMOD Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/) by rik you already mentionned, but also  [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/#shell_version=40.5) by JustPerfection includes the option.

Comment: "Change the single line in the extension's json file" -- Awesome!